# Create long SQL Insert Scripts

Tags: regex, notepad++

I get a list of ID numbers in excel. I need to manually create a SQL script to insert these values.

I managed to get a list of values like below into notepad++.

```
(@FeatureID,1,'00000000000'),
(@FeatureID,1,'00000000001'),
(@FeatureID,1,'00000000002'),
```

Now I want to use notepad++ to add the *insert* statement on every 1000th line to complete the SQL script.

Using regex `(.*\r?\n){999}\K`

**Problem**: The regex gets to line 999 but does not go to the end of the line.

**Question**: How do I get to the end of every 999th line, replace the comma add a new line and insert the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO feat.FeatureValidatorValue (FeatureId, ValidatorId, Value) 
    VALUES)
```

Comment: Try `(?:.*\R){999}.*\K,$` and replace with `\r\nINSERT INTO feat.FeatureValidatorValue \(FeatureId, ValidatorId, Value\) 
    VALUES)`

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it - what you want to do is capture those 999 lines in a group and then for its replacement just add your desired string before the captured group:

```
Find:    ((.*\r?\n){999})
Replace: INSERT INTO feat.FeatureValidatorValue (FeatureId, ValidatorId, Value) VALUES \1
```

Make sure that *`.` matches newline* is not ticked.